# Web Scraping (Requests, Beautiful Soup) - need to get a more specific value/text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, coding-efficiency

I am trying to make code that will scrape stock/fund ticket information (the current price). I have a program that currently pulls the desired value. However, it also pulls a bunch of other text from the webpage with it. I'd like to know if it's possible to use requests and bs to scrape the data more efficiently than having to use additional lines of my own code to narrow the output.

Here is the URL I am using: https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/fspsx

Below is the code I currently have, excluding the lines I have to narrow the output.

```
import bs4 
import requests


def scrape():
    res = requests.get('https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/fspsx')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    Current_Level = soup.find_all(class_="intraday__price")
    Current_Level = str(Current_Level)
    print(Current_Level)


scrape()
```

Here is what the output currently looks like with this code:

```
[<h3 class="intraday__price">
<sup class="character">$</sup>
<bg-quote channel="/zigman2/quotes/206347152/realtime" class="value" field="Last" format="0,0.00">48.27</bg-quote>
</h3>]
```

I just want to grab the price value that is near the end of the output. In this case, it is 48.27.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem in this way:

```
import bs4 
import requests

def scrape():
    res = requests.get('https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/fspsx')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    Current_Level = soup.find(class_="intraday__price").find(class_='value').text
    print(Current_Level)

scrape()
```

In my case it works both in the trading session and afterhours.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a CSS selector: `.intraday__price bg-quote` which will select the tag `bg-quote` under the class `intraday__price`.

Inorder to use a CSS selector, use the [`.select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method instead of `.find()`.

```
import bs4
import requests


def scrape():
    res = requests.get('https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/fspsx')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    print(soup.select_one(".intraday__price bg-quote").text)

scrape()
```

Output:

```
48.27
```

Comment: not sure if I might have made a mistake, but it seems like this code doesn't work whenever the market is closed. Do you know what adjustments I need to make to ensure this works when the market is closed?

Answer (score 0):

You were close. You just need to keep going with your extraction. Try:

```
def scrape():
    res = requests.get('https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/fspsx')
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    Current_Level = soup.find(class_="intraday__price") # use 'find' ilo 'find_all'
    if Current_Level is not None:
        quote = Current_Level.find('bg-quote')
        if quote is not None:
            print(quote.text)
            return quote.text
```

Try using "find" instead of "find_all", since it looks like the *class* only appears once on the page. Then make the extra `find()` call to narrow the output further, then the `.text` to extract the value you want.

If you prefer more compact and generic, with some exception-catching, then:

```
def scrape(fund='fspsx'):
    try:
        res = requests.get('https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/' + fund)            
        value = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml').find(class_="intraday__price").find('bg-quote').text
    except Exception:
        value = None
    return value
```